# Android Overlapping Frames OnClick

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an app that displays a bitmap in a custom View object, stored within a fragment. What I am looking to do is have a button the user can click to display a pop up notification containing arbitrary information that will appear over top the bitmap. I would like this to be a fragment container of some sort, so I could put a bunch of different things there, text, images, links etc..

Here is a picture of the effect I am trying to achieve. This is the first part: The bitmap is shown in blue, with the red button.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqIdE.png)

When the user clicks the red button, I want a pop up to appear in generally the upper center of the screen, like so :

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiGvK.png)

I have looked around but I have yet to find a clear example of how to do something like this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

use framelayout for that .. placing ImageView(or your customView) in background and textview (or any other view) on top of that.

like this :-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbHolder">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/titletxt"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:text="" />


    </FrameLayout>
```

also add a Button widget and control the visiblity of the topView ( textview or any other view ) by setting its visibility using. `view.setVisibility()`   method in onClick() method of Button widget